# Issues with Custom Error Messages on ModelForm

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I am trying to override the default error messages So that I could myself define some sentences for the errors but I am unable to override and it's really killing my time. Does Someone know what am I missing?

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy
from .models import *
# Create your models here.

class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    error_messages = {
        'required': ugettext_lazy("This field is mandatory."),
        'invalid': 'Enter a valid number',
        'caps': 'This field if case sensitive' 
        }

    esewa_id = forms.CharField(error_messages=error_messages,
     label='Esewa_Id',
     help_text='This information will be used only for payment purpose.',
     widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'NumberField', 'type':'number', 'placeholder':'Enter your Esewa_Id'}),

     )
    class Meta:
        model=Customer
        fields = ['first_name','second_name','email','image','gender','esewa_id']
```

In **models.py** I have define a Customer model that inherits from the User model and also use validators for the image validation and did mention help_text.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator,MinValueValidator,MaxValueValidator
# Create your models here.
class Customer(models.Model): 
    Gender_Choices=[
        ('Male','Male'),
        ('Female','Female'),
    ]  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True) 
    first_name = models.SlugField(max_length=10, null=True)
    second_name=models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
    
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=140, null=True,blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="thumbnails/profile/%y"
                              ,help_text="This will be uploaded as your profile picture. Only .png and .jpg are accepted"
                              ,validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['png','jpg'])]
                              ,blank=True,null=True)
    gender=models.CharField(choices=Gender_Choices,null=True,max_length=50)
    esewa_id=models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True
                                 ,help_text='This information will be used only for payment purpose.'
                                ,validators=[MinValueValidator(9400000000),MaxValueValidator(9999999999)]
                                 )
    auth_token = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)        

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an error class of type Exception then raise that exception

per https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/user-defined-exception

```
# define Python user-defined exceptions
class Error(Exception):
    """Base class for other exceptions"""
    pass


class ValueTooSmallError(Error):
    """Raised when the input value is too small"""
    pass


class ValueTooLargeError(Error):
    """Raised when the input value is too large"""
    pass


# you need to guess this number
number = 10

# user guesses a number until he/she gets it right
while True:
    try:
        i_num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        if i_num < number:
            raise ValueTooSmallError
        elif i_num > number:
            raise ValueTooLargeError
        break
    except ValueTooSmallError:
        print("This value is too small, try again!")
        print()
    except ValueTooLargeError:
        print("This value is too large, try again!")
        print()

print("Congratulations! You guessed it correctly.")
```

Here is a sample run of this program.

```
Enter a number: 12
This value is too large, try again!

Enter a number: 0
This value is too small, try again!

Enter a number: 8
This value is too small, try again!

Enter a number: 10
Congratulations! You guessed it correctly.
```

Comment: well ya this does work for checking the number and generate exception based on the result but my case is different, I am actually trying to override the error_messages that default forms shows to client/(web browser).